# Make in-memory copy of a zip by iterating over each file of the input

Tags: python, memory, copy, zip

Python, as far as know, does not allow modification of an archived file. That is why I want to:

1. Unpack the zip in memory (zip_in).
2. Go over each file in the zip_in, and change it if needed, then copy it to zip_out. For now I'm happy with just making a copy of a file.
3. Save zip_out.

I was experimenting with `zipfile` and `io` but no luck. Partially because I'm not sure how all that works and which object requires which output.

## Working Code

```
import os
import io
import codecs
import zipfile

# Make in-memory copy of a zip file
# by iterating over each file in zip_in
# archive.
#
# Check if a file is text, and in that case
# open it with codecs.

zip_in = zipfile.ZipFile(f, mode='a')
zip_out = zipfile.ZipFile(fn, mode='w')
for i in zip_in.filelist:
    if os.path.splitext(i.filename)[1] in ('.xml', '.txt'):
        c = zip_in.open(i.filename)
        c = codecs.EncodedFile(c, 'utf-8', 'utf-8').read()
        c = c.decode('utf-8')
    else:
        c = zip_in.read(i.filename)
    zip_out.writestr(i.filename, c)
zip_out.close()
```

## Old Example, With a Problem

```
# Make in-memory copy of a zip file
# by iterating over each file in zip_in
# archive.
#
# This code below does not work properly.

zip_in = zipfile.ZipFile(f, mode='a')
zip_out = zipfile.ZipFile(fn, mode='w')
for i in zip_in.filelist:
    bc = io.StringIO() # what about binary files?
    zip_in.extract(i.filename, bc)
    zip_out.writestr(i.filename, bc.read())
zip_out.close()
```

The error is `TypeError: '_io.StringIO' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZipFile.extract()` expects a filename, not a file-like object to write to.  Instead, use `ZipFile.read(name)` to get the contents of the file.  It returns the byte string so will work fine with binary files.  Text files may require decoding to unicode.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Combined with `codecs` and your tip I solved this.